# Calculate progressbar value for multiple file upload

Tags: c#, winforms, file-upload, progress-bar

I wrote a small script for multiple file uploads including a progressbar for status information.
Now I am wondering how to calculate the pogressbar value regarding all selected files for the upload.
The file upload works with a BackgroundWorker that is initialized as follows:

```
public Form()
{
    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
    worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
}
```

A button click opens the file dialog and the BackgroundWorker starts its work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (worker.IsBusy)
        {
            worker.CancelAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
            od.Multiselect = true;
            if (od.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)
                {
                    progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Minimum;
                }

                string ftpServerIP = textBox1.Text;
                string ftpUserID = textBox2.Text;
                string ftpPassword = textBox3.Text;

                List<object> arguments = new List<object>();
                arguments.Add(progressBar1.Value);
                arguments.Add(od.FileNames);
                arguments.Add(ftpServerIP);
                arguments.Add(ftpUserID);
                arguments.Add(ftpPassword);

                worker.RunWorkerAsync(arguments);
            }
        }
}
```

As the BackgroundWorker started its work the FTP connection gets established to transfer all files from the FileOpenDialog. At the end of the following code is my sample for the calculated progressbar that has to be changed to meet the file sizes total:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<object> arguments = e.Argument as List<object>;
        int percentFinished = (int)arguments[0];
        string[] fileNames = arguments[1] as string[];
        string ftpServerIP = arguments[2] as string;
        string ftpUserID = arguments[3] as string;
        string ftpPassword = arguments[4] as string;

        while (!worker.CancellationPending && percentFinished < 100)
        {
            foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
            {
                FileInfo fileInf = new FileInfo(fileName);

                // Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
                reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + fileInf.Name));

                // FTP Credentials
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);

                // By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is not closed after a command is executed.
                reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;

                // Specify the command to be executed.
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                // Specify the data transfer type.
                reqFTP.UseBinary = true;

                // Notify the server about the size of the uploaded file
                reqFTP.ContentLength = fileInf.Length;

                // The buffer size is set to 2kb
                int buffLength = 2048;

                byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];

                int contentLen;

                // Opens a file stream (System.IO.FileStream) to read the file to be uploaded
                FileStream fs = fileInf.OpenRead();

                try
                {
                    // Stream to which the file to be upload is written
                    Stream strm = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();

                    // Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
                    contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);

                    // Until Stream content ends
                    while (contentLen != 0)
                    {
                        // Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
                        strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
                        contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
                    }

                    // Close the file stream and the Request Stream
                    strm.Close();
                    fs.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Upload Error");
                }
            }

            // ToDO: Calculate progressBar
            percentFinished++;
            worker.ReportProgress(percentFinished);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
        e.Result = percentFinished;
    }
```

**THE SOLUTION**
I just had to remove the timeout and the worker reports correct values.

```
 percentFinished++;
 worker.ReportProgress(percentFinished);
 //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you right but let's give it a shot.
Since you have the number of items to be uploaded in your `string[]` array, you can set your `ProgressBar`'s `Maximum` to the number of elements at the beginning.

```
ProgressBar1.Value = 0;
ProgressBar1.Maximum = fileNames.Length;
```

At the end of each loop, you can simply increment the value of your ProgressBar's value with `ProgressBar1.Value += 1;`

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

    //Blah blah blah
    string[] fileNames = arguments[1] as string[];

    ProgressBar1.Value = 0;
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = fileNames.Length;


    while (!worker.CancellationPending && percentFinished < 100)
    {
        foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
        {
            //Blah blah blah
            ProgressBar1.Value += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I got your question right.

---

**Edit**: For each file, you could probably play around the `BackgroundWorker`'s `ProgressChanged` event.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

But make sure your `BackgroundWorker`'s `WorkerReportsProgress` is set to `true`.

```
backgroundWorker2.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

Comment: Where do you pay attention to percentFinished? The progressbar gets passed a percentage value. When it is equal 100% it has finished. progressBar1.Maximum is always 100. How do I calculate the progress considering fileNames.Length and percentage?

Comment: That's my point, you don't need to use separate variables etc for it, as you have a "total elements" and "mapped elements" in your code. The Maximum value of the progress bar does not have to be 100, you can simply set its Maximum to the number of elements of your array, and increase the value by one every time you finish an upload. Am I getting your logic wrong? Plus, if you wanna calculate a percentage as a numerical value, it would be something like `int percResult = mappedElements * 100 / totalElements;`

Comment: Thats's the point: When I have only one file with a size of 50 MB then when I would use your logic the progressbar would be zero until the 50 MB are uploaded and then switch to 1. Right? My intention is to recognize which file size is already uploaded, e.g. 20 MB of 50 MB of one file and display 40% uploaded on the progressBar...

Comment: ooooh now I understand what you mean. Have you tried playing around the `ProgressChanged` event of `BackgroundWorker`? I am updating my answer for a kick start for you

Comment: Posted the Solution at top so that it works for everyone who reads this.